# Find section in a file and append at the bottom of the section

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am trying to find a way in bash to include a line within a section of the file.

Particularly, if I have a section like:

```
%salary
1213
3344
23343
33
%end

%employees
joe
mark 
adam 
%end
```

I want to add a new employee to the above file (say, george) in the employees section just before %end section of the employees.

How can I do that in bash?

Comment: does anybody know sed solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two more awk ways

```
awk '/%employees/||p&&/%end/{p=!p;if(!p)print "George"}1' file
```

or

```
awk '/%employees/,/%end/{if(/%end/)print "George"}1' file
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/%employees/,/%end/{/%end/iGeorge' -e '}' file
```

Insert `George` before the `%end` in the range between `%employee` .. `%end`.

N.B the program must use 2 statements as the `i` command is terminated by a newline. An alternative using Bash is:

```
sed $'/%employees/,/%end/{/%end/iGeorge\n}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`awk(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/awk/) would probably be easiest in this case:

```
/%employees/ { INSERT=1 }

/%end/ {
    if (INSERT == 1) print "george"
    INSERT=0
}

{ print $0 }
```

Example:

```
$ awk -f script input 
%salary
1213
3344
23343
33
%end

%employees
joe
mark 
adam 
george
%end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, i would do like below.

```
$ perl -00pe 's/(?s)((?:^|\n)%employees.*?)(?=%end)/\1george\n/g' file
%salary
1213
3344
23343
33
%end

%employees
joe
mark 
adam 
george
%end
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `awk`

```
awk -v RS= -vFS='\n' -vOFS='\n' '/^%employees/{$NF="george\n"$NF};
  {printf "%s%s", $0, RT}' file
%salary
1213
3344
23343
33
%end

%employees
joe
mark     
adam 
george
%end
```

Comment: If you change `RT` to `ORS ORS` you will get a solution that does not need `gnu awk`, but you will get one extra blank line at end.